# Python running DNS lookups on a list of IP addresses from .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse-dns

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get python to do a DNS lookup for every IP address in my text file. I am getting a TypeError: getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None. Can anyone lend a hand with this?

```
import socket

ip_list = open('output.txt', 'r')
ais = socket.getaddrinfo(ip_list, 0)

print(ais)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `file` iteable object directly as argument to `socket.getaddrinfo` when you need to iterate over the file iterator and pass the strings to the function instead. Assuming each line contains an IP:

```
with open('output.txt') as f:
    for ip in f:
        out = socket.getaddrinfo(ip, 0)
        ...
```

Notes:

- Use `with open...` context manager to `close()` the file object after automatically without explicitly needing to call `close()` even in case of error
- By default `open()` opens a file in read (`r`) mode, so specifying `r` is redundant, would not hurt BTW.